# How to generate a matrix of boxplots, like pairs(..) does?

Tags: r

If you call [`pairs(...)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/pairs) on a dataframe it generates an NXN matrix of scatter plots. Like the following:

```
library(ISLR)
pairs(MyAuto)
```

Generates:

[image]

I am looking for a way to generate boxplots instead of scatterplots in the same form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `panel=` argument of the `pairs` function, define a new function based on `boxplot`, that sets `new=TRUE` in `par` and has a `...` argument.

```
panbox <- function(x, ...) {par(new=TRUE);boxplot(x)}

pairs(mtcars[1:4], panel=panbox)
```

[image]